# Xamarin Forms Json Service Insert Data

Tags: c#, json, post, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add a record to the json service in my application. How can I do this via Service Url. Here is my code.

```
CustomerModel customer = new CustomerModel();
                customer.Name = entryCompanyName.Text;
                customer.Title = entryCompanyTitle.Text;
                customer.PhoneNumber = entryTelephone.Text;
                customer.FaxNumber = entryFax.Text;
                customer.Email = entryEmail.Text;
                customer.CityId = 6444;

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
                string sContentType = "application/json";
                string path = "service url";
                HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
                var task = Client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType));
```

I'm trying M. Wiśnicki's solution, but I took this error

I did not get an error when I added System.net :( Where do i make mistakes?

[image]

Comment: What problem you have with this code?

Comment: It can not find these methods;
GetRequestStreamAsync
GetResponseAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
public static async Task<string> PostEntityToApi<T>(string yourMethodUrl, T yourModel)
  {
    try
    {
        if (_httpClient == null)
        {
           _httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(yourWebSiteUrl) };
        }

        var stringContentInput = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(yourWebSiteUrl. + apiUrl), stringContentInput);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }

        var stringAsync = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        LoggingManager.Error("Received error response: " + stringAsync);

        return stringAsync;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WebRequest`, this sample working for me, i use it in my app.

This is System.Net.WebRequest class, here you find [doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.WebRequest/).

```
 public async Task<string> PostSample(object data, string uri)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:  
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        var itemToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(itemToSend);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Dispose();
        }

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:  
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:  
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                return message;
            }
        }
    }
```